# Excel Function to split word without any specific character

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

If I input the word, helloiamback in the excel cell. I want to use the excel function to split the word characters in every cell. So it will be like this.
I thought of using this function,

```
 =LEFT(text,FIND(character,text)-1)
```

but there is no specific character to split.

For example:

```
helloiamback 

h e l l o i a m b a c k
```

Comment: `SEQUENCE()` is not available on `Excel2010`. So, remove this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SEQUENCE` function is what you are looking for. You can use it with `MID` to get the output you desire.

Try `=MID(A1, SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)), 1)`

[image]

Comment: Or since Excel2010 is tagged: `=IFERROR(MID($A$1,COLUMNS($A:A),1),"")` to be dragged to the right